# Scrape JSON Data in Python

Tags: python

Trying to scrape following json data from a link: I am trying to get the 'ID' values in a list

```
{"lister":[{"id":12345,"name":"ES","only":fal},{"id":67899,"name":"FS","only":gal}]}
```

I have tried following:

```
url = 'link'
r = session.get(url,headers=headers)


js = r.json()
user_id = js["lister"]['id']

print (user_id)
```

I get error:

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What is `session`? Is this the`requests` module?

Comment: The response you get from the server is empty. We can't help you with that without knowing which url you're contacting.

Comment: Considering it is complaining about the first character, check the raw  stuff returned in `r.content` to see if its really json or perhaps an error page or something.

Comment: As an aside, once you get the json, you'll want `js["lister"][0]['id']` to get the first ID, or `for record in js["lister"]: print(record["id"]` for them all.

Comment: its not valid JSON try hier; http://jsonviewer.stack.hu

Comment: session is requests, with r.content I get output: b'{"lister":[{"id": 12345,"name":"ES,"only":fal},{"id":5678,"name":"LS","only":tal}]}' @tdelaney

Comment: So i solved the problem json.loads(r.content)['lister'][1]['id'], prints the second value, how can i print all values in a list @tdelaney

Comment: `for value in json.loads(r.content)["lister"]: print(value["id"])`